# How to typecast a string to a menu control

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, submenu

I have multiple asp menu control in my **aspx** page.ex:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" StaticDisplayLevels="3">
</asp:Menu>
<asp:Menu ID="Menu2" runat="server" StaticDisplayLevels="3">
</asp:Menu>
```

i am adding the menu item dynamically from the codebehind.
for that to make the code short i am storing the id in a string array.like this

```
string[] menuarray={"Menu1","Menu2"};
```

and i am attempting to typecast the menuarrayitems to Menu in order to add the items like this

```
(Menu)menuarray[1].Items.Add("text","value");
```

but this is not working.What I am doing wrong??
Any Help would be appreciated..
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you cant cast a string to a control. You have to find the control based on the ID or just do: `Menu[] menuArray = {Menu1, Menu2};`

Comment: However `(Menu)menuarray[1].Items.Add("text","value");` doesn´t make any sense at all since `Items.Add` is of type `void`, which you can´t cast to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but the following may work:

```
HtmlElement myElement = myBrowser.Document.GetElementById("Menu1");
Menu menu1 = (Menu) myElement;
menu1.Items.Add("text", "value");
```